# Type.GetEnumUnderlyingType() replacement for .net35

Tags: c#, .net, f#, .net-3.5

I'm looking for a way to replicate the functionality of [`Type.GetEnumUnderlyingType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getenumunderlyingtype(v=vs.100).aspx) which is missing in .net35.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`Enum.GetUnderlyingType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getunderlyingtype(v=vs.90).aspx) instead:

> Returns the underlying type of the specified enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the implementation for `GetEnumUnderlyingType` from `Type`:

```
public virtual Type GetEnumUnderlyingType()
{
    if (!this.IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException(
            Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_MustBeEnum"), "enumType");
    FieldInfo[] fields = this.GetFields(
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (fields == null || fields.Length != 1)
        throw new ArgumentException(
            Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_InvalidEnum"), "enumType");
    return fields[0].FieldType;
}
```